# Java Rectangle class area/perimeter outputting 0

Tags: java, getter-setter

When I get run my Rectangle.java, I can get the inputted length and width in the Rectangle, but when I attempt to calculate the area/perimeter with a getter I get a zero as the result

I attempted to add and remove the setters, put in the getter/setter methods within the getArea and getPerimeter, but nothing seems to work

```
//Code provided by the teacher as a template 
Rectangle temp = new Rectangle();
        temp.print();
        System.out.println();

        temp.setLength(2.5);
        temp.setWidth(3.0);
        //Consider how your rectangle will change after setting the length and width to specific values.
        temp.print();

        System.out.println();

        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(3.5,2);
        r.print();




//My Class

public class Rectangle 
{
    private static double length;
    private static double width;
    private static double perimeter;
    private static double area;

    public Rectangle(double length, double width)
    {
        setLength(length);
        setWidth(width);
    }

    public Rectangle()
    {

    }

    public static double getLength() 
    {
        return length;
    }
    public static void setLength(double length) 
    {
        Rectangle.length = length;
    }
    public static double getWidth() 
    {
        return width;
    }
    public static void setWidth(double width)
    {
        Rectangle.width = width;
    }   
    public static double getPerimeter(double length, double width) 
    {
        return 2*width+2*length;
    }

    public static double getArea(double length, double width) 
    {
        area= getLength()*getWidth();
        return length*width;
    }


    public static String print() 
    {
        String Rectangle = new String();
        System.out.println("This rectangle has a length of "+length+" and a width of "+width);
        System.out.println("The area of the rectangle is: "+ area);
        System.out.println("The perimeter of the rectangle is: "+ perimeter);
        return Rectangle;

    }
}
```

No error messages.

Output:

This rectangle has a length of 0.0 and a width of 0.0
The area of the rectangle is: 0.0
The perimeter of the rectangle is: 0.0

This rectangle has a length of 2.5 and a width of 3.0
The area of the rectangle is: 0.0
The perimeter of the rectangle is: 0.0

This rectangle has a length of 3.5 and a width of 2.0
The area of the rectangle is: 0.0
The perimeter of the rectangle is: 0.0

Comment: can you give your complete rectangle class ?

Comment: Adding the full rectangle class as requested. I am new to this place and it said "essential parts".

Comment: Was it really that obvious?! Thank you so much ⵍⵢⴻⵙ. Question closed. I am quite new so am prone to silly mistakes.

Comment: `String Rectangle = new String()`. I recommend you change the name of this variable, it is *very* confusing.

Comment: I have figured out the simple issue from one of the comments, but I will keep reading this thread for good coding practices, since I want to be actually good

Comment: Since the purpose of `print()` is to print the info of the rectangle, it should actually have return type `void`. `String Rectangle` does not serve any purpose in your program.

Comment: @HlibTarabrov is your issue fixed ?

Comment: @ⵍⵢⴻⵙ Yes... it was way too obvious. Thank you for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the print method and call perimeter and area method so that those variables get the required values

```
 public static String print() 
{
    getPerimeter(length,width);
    getArea(length,width);
    String Rectangle = new String();
    System.out.println("This rectangle has a length of "+length+" and a width of "+width);
    System.out.println("The area of the rectangle is: "+ area);
    System.out.println("The perimeter of the rectangle is: "+ perimeter);
    return Rectangle;

}
```

I would suggest not to use static key words as the values will not be bound to the object